Multipoint evaluation in Lagrange basis on subset smaller than degree
Setup. Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field with a multiplicative subgroup $E = \{e_1, \dots, e_k\}$ of order $k$. Given a list $y = y_1, \dots, y_k\in \mathbb{F}$ let $p$ be the unique polynomial of degree $k-1$ s.t. $p(e_i) = y_i$ for all $i\in [k]$.
Let $E'=\{e'_1, \dots, e'_t\}\not\subset E$ be a additive coset of a subgroup of $E$ (i.e. $t < k$).
Problem. Given $y$ as input, can we compute $p(e'_i)$ for all $i\in [t]$ in time $O_{\log|\mathbb{F}|}(k + t\;\mathrm{polylog}\;k)$? That is, if $t = k / \mathrm{polylog}(k)$, the computation would run in time $O_{\log|\mathbb{F}|}(k)$. Note that if $t = O(k)$, FFT solves this problem in time $O_{\log|\mathbb{F}|}(k + k \;\mathrm{polylog}\; k) = O(k \;\mathrm{polylog}\; k)$.
Relaxation. It would still be interesting to solve this problem over any finite field $\mathbb{F}$ and any (disjoint) subsets $E, E'\subset \mathbb{F}$ of size $k,t$, respectively, in time $O_{\log|\mathbb{F}|}(k\log\log k + t\;\mathrm{polylog}\;k)$.
cross-posted from TCS overflow (+4 days from initial posting). @Command Master suggested finding $r = p \mod \prod_i (x - e_i)$ and the evaluating on $E'$ (in time $O_{\log|\mathbb{F}|}(t\;\mathrm{polylog}\; t)$ using FFT). $r$ can be found in time $O_{\log|\mathbb{F}|}(k\log k)$ using Sieveking-Kung division, but that is not sufficiently efficient.
